# Swift 4 - Json decoder

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have searched a lot and tried my best but I am stuck.

I try to extract a string from a Json request (from Pexel API):

Here is my code to extract the json (with Alamofire and SwiftyJson imported)

```
  func retrieveapi () {

        let apiKey = "563*****************0c7eae"




        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "5********************ae",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]

        Alamofire.request("https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=Spain+query&per_page=15&page=1", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value {

              print ("json \(json)") 
}}}
```

The log of the print("json") is below

```
json {
    "next_page" = "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search/?page=2&per_page=15&query=Spain+query";
    page = 1;
    "per_page" = 15;
    photos =     (
                {
            height = 2661;
            id = 52062;
            photographer = "tyler hendy";
            src =             {
                landscape = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=627&w=1200";
                large = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940";
                large2x = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940";
                medium = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350";
                original = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg";
                portrait = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=800";
                small = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=130";
                square = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=1200&w=1200";
                tiny = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/52062/pexels-photo-52062.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&h=200&w=280";
            };
            url = "https://www.pexels.com/photo/water-architecture-colourful-church-52062/";
            width = 4000;
        },
                {  // A lot of more results....
```

I just want to extract :

The first result of "landscape".

I have tried to pass it to a Dict ,to an array, to make it Codable.. but it was unsucessfull. 
Could someone kindly help me and tell me how I can extract the First (only the first) result of "landscape" ?

Thanks a lot !

Edit: found it and thanks for the tips !

I put it for anyone who was stuck like me..

```
    if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
        let listData = dictionary["photos"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        let photoDict = listData[1]
        let srcDict = photoDict["src"]
        let landscapeStr = srcDict!["landscape"]
        print ("landscapeStr \(landscapeStr!)")

    }   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Remember to watch your () and {}.  First jsonDict, then let photos = json["photos"], is an array of dictionaries. So you'll want photos[0] or .firstObject. So photoDict = photos[0]. Then let srcDict = photoDict["src"];  Now you can finally get the landscape let landscapeStr = ... you may be able to guess it. Review some json and get used to testing for null/optionals. Always test and ensure you're grabbing the one before/above before you get the next, and get used to logging/printing results! The debugger is great

Comment: Hello @AshleyMills Thanks for your help/tips.

Comment: What type is `response.result.value`? With what are you decoding? What error do you get?

Comment: Hello @Fabian. I found the solution , it's on my edit!

Comment: @Victor Ah I didn‘t parse that part, very good! Its usual to post a separate answer from the question so others can upvote it btw :-).

Comment: @Fabian, ok :) . Here is the solution :   if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
        let listData = dictionary["photos"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]
        let photoDict = listData[1]
        let srcDict = photoDict["src"]
        let landscapeStr = srcDict!["landscape"]
        print ("landscapeStr \(landscapeStr!)")

    }   }

Comment: @Victor I ment adding your answer like the guy below ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Decodable.

```
struct Post : Decodable {

    var photo : Photo?
} 

struct Photo : Decodable {

    var source : Source?
}

struct Source : Decodable {

    var landscape : String?
}

Alamofire.request("https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=Spain+query&per_page=15&page=1", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    guard let data = response.results.value {

         let post = createObject(json: data, decodable: Post.self)
    }
}

func createObject<D: Decodable> (json : [String: Any], decodable: D.Type) throws -> D {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(decodable, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: snapshot, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys))
}
```